# Grouping Non-Resourceful routes in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-routing

I have 2 routes like this:

```
get '/quotation/cep_validator', to: 'quotation#cep_validator'
get '/quotation/price', to: 'quotation#price'
```

They are not RESTful but as you can see both habe the same beginning in the URL and the same controller.

Is there any way to group them together, similar to resource routes?

```
route :quotation do
  get 'cep_validator'
  get 'price'
end
```

Comment: You can use member or collection routes block.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
resource :quotation, only: [] do
  collection do
    get :cep_validator
    get :price
  end
end
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you are looking for:

```
controller :quotation do
  get 'cep_validator' => :cep_validator
  get 'price' => :price
end
```

Comment: This generates a route without the /quotation/:
availability GET    /availability(.:format)                     quotation#availability

Comment: You're right. I'll edit. The string you are placing after get should reflect what address is entered.